# How do I integrate Crashpad with my daemon application in linux? Is there any implementation guide?

Tags: linux

How do I integrate Crashpad with my daemon application in linux? Is there any implementation guide? I did not find any official recommended steps on chromium project site.

Comment: Lots of good hits: [crashpad integration](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=crashpad+integration). Be careful of devices like these. They can leak sensitive information, like user passwords and private keys. User's don't want their secrets shipped to a third party or developer.

Comment: For example https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/breakpad/

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to build Crashpad and link `libbase.a`, `libclient.a` and `libutil.a` with your application.

Additionally you'll need to add `$CRASHPAD_DIR/include` and `$CRASHPAD_DIR/include/third_party/mini_chromium/mini_chromium` as include directories.

The following `clang++` command will build and link Crashpad with the source file `main.cpp`:

```
clang++ $PROJECT_DIR/main.cpp \
    $CRASHPAD_DIR/lib/libclient.a \
    $CRASHPAD_DIR/lib/libutil.a \
    $CRASHPAD_DIR/lib/libbase.a \
    -I$CRASHPAD_DIR/include \
    -I$CRASHPAD_DIR/include/third_party/mini_chromium/mini_chromium \
    -o$OUT_DIR/$MODULE_NAME \
    -g \
    -Wl,--build-id
```

Please note that the order in which you specify the Crashpad libraries is important! `libbase.a` needs to be the last library specified otherwise clang++ will exit with an error.

Additionally, the flags `-g` and `-Wl,--build-id` are required if you want function names and line numbers when you unwind the minidump file.

A sample application built with clang++ on Ubuntu can be found [here](https://github.com/BugSplat-Git/myUbuntuCrasher). A full tutorial for building and integrating Crashpad with your own application and using `dump_syms`, `symupload` and `minidump_stackwalk`, can be found [here](https://www.bugsplat.com/docs/sdk/linux/).